# how to include "omp.h" without specifying exact path on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, cmake, openmp

I can build my project by using

```
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401/include/libiomp/omp.h"
```

and also `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fopenmp")`in the CMakeLists.txt

but what should I do to  just `#include <omp.h>`?

When I `brew list`, I have clang-omp, libivmp, gcc installed. I found that omp.h by using `locate omp.h`.

And my `gcc -v` prints:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Configured with: ../gcc-5.1.0/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.0 (GCC)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GCC comes with its own OpenMP implementation (libgomp) and the path to its `omp.h` is added automatically when `-fopenmp` is specified. As far as I see, you want to link against the Intel OpenMP runtime which provides a compatibility layer with libgomp API. You should be able to simply use `-fopenmp` and `#include <omp.h>` at **compile time** and then link against IOMP **without** the `-fopenmp` flag (if GCC is also used as linker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a command line option for the C or C++ compiler:

```
-I /usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401/include/libiomp
```

(space between `-I` and path optional) on the compiler command line.  You might well have a variable that identifies `/usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401` as the location where the OMP code is installed, because the chances are you also need an option `-L /usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401/lib` (space optional again) to pick up the libraries when you link, too.

Fixing that in your `CMakeLists.txt` file is a somewhat separate discussion, but you're likely to be able to find some exemplars that will help there.

Comment: Hn.. Thank you. I thought there could be an environment variable or something after the brew install.

Comment: Not to forget: directory & file names with spaces. In this case his path needs to start and end with `"` (_quote_), otherwise the path gets splitted in multiple arguments.

Comment: @Youka: Which space? There is no space in the name quoted in the question. Yes, in theory you're right. In practice, people writing programs generally assume that there are no spaces in pathnames. I used to have a directory `External Source Repositories` with various SVN, Git and Mercurial clones in it. It didn't last long; none of the autoconfiscated software (code using `autoconf` and relatives) handled the path name with blanks in it. The directory is now `External-Source-Repositories`. I'm not talking about shabby third-rate projects having problems; these were mainstream FLOSS projects.